# Chroma Key - Removing Video Green Screen - Free Software

Tags: gratis, video-editing

I'm looking for a piece of software that can remove the background of a video for free.  Similar to Adobe Premiere, which I plan on buying soon but cannot currently.

**Requirement**

- Free
- Can remove the green screen without leaving trails behind (if it isn't noticeable that is okay)
- Doesn't have to be PERFECTLY green (so shadows etc don't mess it up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free version of **[Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/)** is a video editor that enables you to (amongst other things):

- perform a chroma key on a clip (in other words: "it removes the green screen"),
- export the result with a resolution of 720p.

It is a powerful piece of software that takes a bit of practice to get used to the ergonomic of the controls but there are some good **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdY5LaSnlqA)** on the internet.

Exporting a 1080p video is a feature only available with the "Pro" version (i.e. the "not gratis" version).